# Parsing HTML (android)

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

What's wrong? When I'm clicking the BTN it's stopping (unexpected). This is the part of code which works wrong, the lib I use is Jsoap. Help me pls

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://hitage.ru").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Elements nodes = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueStarting("class", "page node");
    }
});
```

Comment: Post your LogCat stack trace. It seems you might be getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make network calls on the UI thread.  You need to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or something similar.  Also, make sure you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.